# Nginx Server Side Includes and url rewrite

Tags: nginx, server-side-includes

I'm trying to do something that looks very difficult for me.

I need to embed a live blog remote HTML url inside my rails app and I don't want to use iframes for SEO.

I'm trying to use SSI.

I understand that I cannot use SSI with remote URL, but I'm trying to configure NGINX to have a local url that redirect to a remote url.

My liveblog url is something like this

```
https://liveblog.example.it/api/upload-raw/blogs/xxxxxxxxxx/index.html
```

I'm trying to add in nginx configuration something like this...

```
server {
....
  location /live_blog_embed {
    proxy_pass @live_blog; # or use "try_files" to provide fallback
  }

  location @live_blog {
    proxy_pass https://liveblog.example.it/api/upload-raw/blogs/xxxxxxxxxx/index.html;
  }
....
}
```

And then in my application

```
<!--# include virtual="/live_blog_embed?id=xxxxxx" -->
```

I cannot understand how can I pass my blog id from the html to the nginx configuration...

Any hint?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, I don’t know how to pass params...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
proxy_pass https://liveblog.example.it/api/upload-raw/blogs/$arg_id/index.html;
```

The `$arg_` prefix is used in nginx to use query arguments as variables.